# Maintaining session state inside an iFrame

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, iframe

not sure if I'm going crazy, but I am having issues with session state inside an iFrame. Its a simple setup of one domain inside another. I dont need to share anything across the domains, all I want to do is embed a website inside another website and I want that embedded site to be able to log in / edit / update / etc using cookies / session state.

To remove all the complexities of server farms / shared sql session state etc, I created a simple html page served up by IIS that simply has an iFrame tag inside of it that call my site. All loads and is great, but the moment I try and log in, I get stuck in an endless loop of log in screens as the session is re-created with each request and I get logged out etc...

What am I missing? was there some uber browser security upgrade that cam into effect recently?

Any guidance would be awesome.

PS. I've got the p3p headers in place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for those experiencing the same pain as me, it turn that a cumulative update from microsoft changed the default cooke behavior from SameSite=None -> SameSite=Lax.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4533013/kb4533013-cumulative-update-for-net-framework

to fix and I believe this is just a temporary workaround ( Message in Chrome console -> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at  was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at  and ), is to add this to your web.config

```
<sessionState cookieSameSite="None" ..other attributes here.. />
```