# ASP.net MVC - Losing Session State

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iframe, session-state

I have an MVC page (.net 4.7.2).  That page has a partial view.  The partial view contains an iFrame to a third party.

```
[MVC Page [Partial View [iFrame to third party]]]
```

A user will interact with a form hosted by the third party iFrame.  Data is submitted to the third party.  After the third party processes the submission, the iFrame posts data to my application via a predetermined URL. So the iFrame starts off displaying the third party form, then posts its response back to my application - all within the iFrame.

However, The MVC page receiving the post from the third party doesn't have access to the session state of the application. It's like the MVC app is treating the initial MVC page as a different session than the return page within the iFrame.  It's the same app, same domain, same browser.

Why can't the MVC page in the iFrame access the same session?

How can I access the session information?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Session Variables not saved when page is in an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368750/session-variables-not-saved-when-page-is-in-an-iframe)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintaining session state inside an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59844569/maintaining-session-state-inside-an-iframe)